# -bash: ./deploy.sh: Permission denied , ERROR: script returned exit code 126

Tags: java, bash, spring-boot, jenkins

I am trying to implement continuous deployment using Jenkins and that involves sending a jar file to a remote server and start the jar once its on the remote server.

> The problem is that i keep getting access denied error and i have tried every account i have on my remote and local server nothing seems to work. I get the same Error.

**Jenkins file**

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {

        stage ('Packaging stage') {

            steps {
                withMaven(maven : 'Maven') {
                    sh 'mvn clean install'
                }
            }
        }

        stage ('Deploy To Dev Server') {

             steps {
                sh './deploy.sh'
         }
       }
    }

}
```

**deploy.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn scp -P 10022 /var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/hector/eureka-naming-server/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/eureka-naming-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
myUserName@myRemoteServer.net:/home/myname/repository/eureka-service-deploy

expect "password: "

send "myPassword\r"

expect "$ "
send "other_command_to_execute_on_remote\r"
expect "$ "
send "exit\r"
echo "Successfully sent file"
```

[image]

Comment: What are the permissions on `deploy.sh`? Is the execute permission set such that the Jenkins user can execute it?

Comment: i am not really sure where to set such permissions, could you please assist with a guide on how to set such permissions

Comment: You can see a file's read, write and execute permissions with `ls -l`, this is a good introductory read on the subject: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-linux-permissions

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It looks like your `deploy.sh` isn't executable, as you can see with the error code 126  “**command not executable**".

```
ls -l path/to/
```

the output should be similar to:

```
-rw-r--r--    1 user  staff      402 Aug  1 10:55 deploy.sh
```

If your file hasn't the executable flag, you should change the access right with `chmod`, something like:

```
chmod +x path/to/deploy.sh
```

the result should be then something like (notice the 4th char **x**):

```
-rwxr--r--    1 user  staff      402 Aug  1 10:55 deploy.sh
```

If your script is committed to git, you can also do:

```
git update-index --chmod=+x path/to/deploy.sh
```

Comment: The deploy.sh file is a part of the springboot project

Comment: ./deploy.sh: line 2: spawn: command not found
./deploy.sh: line 3: myUserName@myRemoteServer.net:/home/myname/repository/eureka-service-deploy: No such file or directory
./deploy.sh: line 7: expect: command not found
./deploy.sh: line 10: send: command not found
./deploy.sh: line 14: expect: command not found
./deploy.sh: line 15: send: command not found
./deploy.sh: line 16: expect: command not found
./deploy.sh: line 17: send: command not found

Comment: i get the above error after i try chmod +x path/to/deploy.sh

Comment: Now you have a new error saying that now the command `spawn` doesn't exist, which shows that your `deploy.sh` is now executable. I don't know if your `expect` environment is properly configured with the correct binaries.

Comment: I ended up using a plugin in Jenkind called publish over ssh

Comment: Worked for me fine!
gave the file permissions to execute as mentioned above and then checked in to github, worked well.
Easy!

Comment: My Git version (2.28.0) automatically updates the git index when you change a file's permission. I did a `git diff` on a file whose permissions I changed and I got the following ```deploy-scripts/bitbucket/install_phantomjs.sh w/deploy-scripts/bitbucket/install_phantomjs.sh changed file mode from 100644 to 100755```

You can the git add and push!