# Permission denied for deploy.sh file in scripts folder

Tags: deployment, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've getting permission denied upon running scripts/deploy.sh prod in wsl2. Am I supposed to run a chmod command?

I've previously tried to follow this [-bash: ./deploy.sh: Permission denied , ERROR: script returned exit code 126](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53692805/bash-deploy-sh-permission-denied-error-script-returned-exit-code-126) by entering `chmod +x scripts/deploy.sh` but  when I tried running scripts/deploy.sh prod it tells me the file doesn't exist.

Could someone kindly advice? Thank you!

[image]

[image]

Here's evidence that the file is there:
[image]

Comment: could you please confirm that the file (deploy.sh) you are looking for is exist in the `scripts` directory? because error says it doesn't

Comment: Yes, I've updated the issue - the file is there

Comment: You may have to provide the full path to the script to get it to run.